# Is it always safe to modify view while activity is in background

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask

This probably isn't good practice, but ...

Let's say i have an `AsyncTask` inside a fragment. In the `onPostExecute` of it, i modify a view that is in my activity (like simply enable a button and change the text/color of it).

i tried this and it doesn't seem to crash.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {Thread.sleep(5000);} catch(Exception e){}
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        System.out.println("modifying view");
        mButton.setText("after on Post"); // mButton is some button in the view
    }
}
```

now, i run the task, immediately hit the `HOME` key, and then wait until i see "modifying view" in the log, then later open up the activity again. my button definitely changed its text properly; however, i was wondering if there are any edge cases that i should be aware of that could possibly cause this to mess up?

note: this `mButton` is a view inside a `Fragment` that i create. The reason i ask is because i used to check for `isAttached()` in my `onPostExecute` but that sometimes doesn't change the button, and i'd like to ALWAYS change the button, regardless of whether or not the fragment is attached? although i'm not sure why the page is showing by the fragment is "not attached"

Comment: Might want to ask this question over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Vipar is there an easy way to link/copy this question over, without me having to manually link the two?

Comment: You should be able to just press "Edit" then copy all the text and make the question over on codereview. Then ask for this question to be deleted by pressing the "Delete" button.

Comment: @Vipar i can copy this over manually (if there's no automatic porting). But why is this question unacceptable for StackOverflow?

Comment: @Vipar i was under the impression that StackOverflow gets more eyeballs and i'd ideally like to have my question answered quicker and more accurately

Comment: Because currently you have working code. You are essentially asking for code review which that site is made for. Stackoverflow was generally made for code that doesn't compile, work or doesn't work as intended.

Comment: There are probably edge cases for everything! :)  I can't see obvious ones here.  You are simply updating a property of a UI element.  The window manager will take care of updating anything relevant in the display when the associated activity comes to the foreground again.  Another way of thinking about this that for any UI update, the message to repaint the UI is always delivered sometime after the update takes place.  There can be no guarantee that the updated element is visible, or even in the foreground app, when the message is processed.

Comment: @Simon that is a great explanation, thank you! you should repost that comment as an answer